# Compare list arrays and remove duplicates

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, compare, unityscript

I have 2 list arrays like this:

```
var list1 = new List.<String>();
var list2 = new List.<String>();
```

Now I want to compare those 2 and remove from list1 if the same exists in list2 but simply can't figure out how to?!?

I am building this in Unity.

Please help. I have searched the net but haven't found anything that could help and i am lost.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can intersect both List like that:

```
list1 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't work in unity and besides... I don't want to add them together, I just want to remove from list1 if the same exists in list2.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the C# syntax, i'm sure you can translate this though.
I would use a foreach loop to collect duplicates first, and then another one to remove them all. The reason to do this in two steps is that you can't modify a list while iterating it.

```
List<string> duplicates = new List<string>;
foreach (string s in list1)
{
    if (list2.Contains(s)) duplicates.Add(s);
}
foreach (string s in duplicates)
{
    list1.Remove(s);
}
```